# Android: How can I define a 45° angle of the view (RelativeLayout) in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, angle, android-orientation

I want to display a line with text on it but it shouldn't be vertical or horizontal it should be in 45° angle. I'm using for a RelativeLayout which contains a TextView and a View ( for the line). With the help of the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams I try to define the x/y position of the  RelativeLayout. The horizontal display already works but how can I change it to become a 45° angle?

```
    RelativeLayout branch_layout = (RelativeLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.createrelativelayout);

    LinearLayout branch_item = new LinearLayout(this);
    branch_item.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    branch_item.setOrientation(1);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pos, pos));
    tv.setId(id);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
    tv.setText(branch_name);
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Paint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(branch_name, 0, branch_name.length(), bounds);
    View underline = new View(this);
    underline.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(bounds.width() + 40, 1));
    underline.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    branch_item_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    branch_item_layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    //x
    params.leftMargin = display.getWidth()/2;
    //y
    params.topMargin = ((display.getHeight()/2)-(((LinearLayout) this
            .findViewById(R.id.createlinearlayout3)).getWidth()/2)-48);

    //end x
    params.bottomMargin = params.leftMargin + bounds.width();
    //end y
    params.rightMargin = (int) (params.leftMargin - (bounds.width()*Math.sin(45)));

    branch_item.addView(tv);
    branch_item.addView(underline);

    branch_item_layout.addView(branch_item, params);
    branch_layout.addView(branch_item_layout);
```

The whole screen implementation is only for "landscape" x 0-800, y 0-440
Right now the

```
first x = 400
first y = 114
end x   = 434
end y   = 371
```

Planned was to display the String and line together in 45° angle. The length of the line orientates on the String width.

Hope anyone can help me with this dilemma,

Saskia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem because of the x and y position was that the relativelayout became very huge.
So I removed the layout branch_item_layout and add the parameter and animation stuff on branch_item.

See you,

Saskia